# How do I easily disable a locale?

Tags: android, localization

I have an app that currently only supports one language.
In order to strip unused localization resources, I've added `resConfigs "nl"` to the defaultConfig in my build.gradle, so no other languages are included.

The issue is that calls like `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG).format(new Date())` still result in a string containing another language.

I am currently using a solution much like the one provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26801256/5554155) to lock the locale to one single language, but it feels very dirty.

What is the recommended way to enable just one (or a few) languages?