# gradle: modify build of library from project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I have a simple question. Is it possible to modify the gradle library build project specific and how?

Following example, I have a library that I use in multiple projects.
Now I want to exclude some files in the library when I build Project_A.

But I want them included when I build Project_B.

[image]

I wonder if its possible to add parameters to the dependencies in the build.gradle file of Projekt_A. Something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':explore_layout', 
        //specify the exclude inside the lib
        sourceSets {
           main {
               java {
                   exclude '**/uncompilable/**'
               }
           }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Why not reusing them in Project_B!

Comment: Have you tried to let `Library` unmodified and let **proguard** do the job to remove all unreferenced code in the linked ` Project_A` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make two source sets in your library project and then depend on the the according configurations that are added for the source sets. This way you can get only one source set for `A` but both for `B`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! In my case there was an even more simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26801256/1797191