Why is my Flutter app having namespace errors?
I am trying to work on my Flutter app, and I have migrated to the declarative apply of Flutter's plugins. However, this has now created another issue that I have no clue how to fix.
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':android_intent'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

     If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

The error is shown above, and I can't figure out why I am getting an error. I have defined a namespace in the app/build.gradle file also, and I am completely lost. Any help would be very appreciated!
android {
    namespace "com.example.cyclesync"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion


Hi :) I'm having the same problem, did you ever find a solution to this? Any thoughts would be appreciated as I'm also going insane on this error :/

@Amy the suggested solution doesn't seem to be working for me. If you find a solution, please do let me know. Thank you!

I think I found the fix for it!! I'll post an anwser soon :)

The dev of 'android_intent' module which you added most likely the recent, needs to update their codes with a namespace to comply. Just as the debug error says

For me this error was happening when importing the package webview_cookie_manager but I've had it happen on others too. For you it seems to triggering specificly on the package android_intent.
To fix this, in your android/build.gradle (NOT android/app/build.gradle), add this gradle script:
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
            project.android {
                if (namespace == null) {
                    namespace project.group
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

So the whole file should look somewhat like:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
            project.android {
                if (namespace == null) {
                    namespace project.group
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

So if the dependency doesn't already have a specified namespace, the code will automatically assign one using the package name.
Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions :)

Hello, thank you so much for your detailed answer. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error - the only difference is that it doesn't take as long for the error to be thrown. Would an alternative solution be to remove the package that is causing the error? If so, how could I do this?

Hmm depends on which package it's throwing the error for, could you edit your question and include the dependencies in your pubspec.yaml? That way I can have a better look at what it's complaining about :)

I suggest deleting the android folder from you project and then running the following command in the terminal at your project's root directory:
flutter create .

This command will recreate your android folder clean and hopefully resolve the namespace issue.

Thank you for your answer. If I delete the android folder from my project, will this not harm my project in some way? Of course, I will make a backup, but I'd rather not have to deal with having to use it!

After you delete the folder and run this command at the root directory of the project ( flutter create . ), the folder will be recreated again clean and hopefully that will resolve your issue. One note, don't forget the period after the after the word create

Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error after taking the suggested steps. Have you got any other ideas please?

Have you tried to run flutter clean command?

I have, but it does not help unfortunately.

The problem is coming from 'android_intent' package you added. The developer of that module needs to update the codes and add a namespace to their project. I don't think the problem is from your own codes

Thank you for your reply. How can I fix this myself? I wish to not rely on someone else fixing their code.

Try this answer here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/45798796/4548543

I had same error with image_gallery_saver and solved this by cloning same dependency from github to folder and adding namespace to the dependencies build.gradel file and using this cloned dependency into my project, it get solved but then I get same error with flutter_tflite I tried the same way but then flutter_tflite started showing their own errors. Sorry for my bad English, try this if it works for you...
